# find_or_create_by not finding, only trying to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Using google oauth for a project. Had it working, but wanted to pull the profile picture to display in my app. Once I was able to display the picture, I logged out and tried to relog back in with the oauth. It is now telling me that the name and email have already been taken. I am using a `find_or_create_by` in my `User` model to find or create by the oauth credentials. I don't know what is causing this as it was working just a bit ago. And now, when I go back to how my code first was, it is not working period. Just giving me the errors bc of validations(trying to create a record instead of finding the record in the database.)

`sessions#create`

```
def create
    if params[:provider].present?
      @user = User.find_or_create_from_auth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
      if @user
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        flash[:notice] = "Logged in as #{@user.name}"
        redirect_to dashboard_path
      end
```

Users model-

```
def self.find_or_create_from_auth(auth)
    find_or_create_by!(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid, password_digest: 'N/A') do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.address = "123 ABC St"
      user.password = 'n/a'
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save
    end
  end
```

Appreciate any help, just not seeing the disconnect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

`find_or_create_by!(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid, password_digest: 'N/A') do |user|`

You only are considering the uid, provider and password_digest. But as your error says `the name and email have already been taken`. Which means that at your users database you have a unique constraint in both. So even when the uid and provider are different, you can't persist a new instance at DB if it matches with another existing record.

So you can remove the unique constraint or add that validation to `find_or_create_by`

Comment: That does work if I take out the validations on the model. But isn't that what `find_or_create_by` supposed to do? Find the record if it already exists otherwise create it?

Comment: find_or_create_by find a record at db with those attributes, what is inside of -> (), if it doesn't found a record that matches those attributes then create a new one. So you are not passing the email and the name, that's why find_or_create_by it's not taking care care about that

Comment: It's weird, I added the email and name to the argument. It was creating multiple records when I took the validations out. I removed the name and email from the argument and reapplied the validations and now it works, but now the image is nil in the view even though it's there as an attribute. lol. Thank you for the assistance. Definitely gives me more to play with:P